# Delete certain lines matching pattern in multiple files in a directory

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed

I have multiple `.csv` files in a directory called `mydirectory`. Each file contains a line that start with `#GENE_ANNOTATIONS`. I want to delete all the lines prior to this line including this line plus one line below this line. I want this to be applied to all the files and save them. Is there any unix/awk/perl command to do this?

Comment: @MattJacob What is it? Would you be kind enough to share that in a not-so-American manner?

Comment: Of course. Show me what you've worked on so far, and I'd be happy to help you fix whatever isn't working with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i '0,/^#GENE_ANNOTATIONS/{/^#GENE_ANNOTATIONS/{N};d;}' mydirectory/*
```

Comment: I think this may not work as intended as each time the sed commands are executed two lines will be read into the pattern space. Perhaps what you intended was that only the last line would read in an extra line i.e. `sed -i '1,/^#GENE_ANNOTATIONS/{/^#GENE_ANNOTATIONS/N;d;}' mydirectory/*`

Comment: @potong: Thank you for this hint. I've updated my answer and fixed a second bug. It works now too, if `#GENE_ANNOTATIONS` is the first line.

Comment: Well done, if you want you could get rid of the curly brackets on the N command reducing it a bit: `sed '1,/^#GENE_ANNOTATIONS/{/^#GENE_ANNOTATIONS/N;d}' file.txt`. Another way that is logically easy for those relatively unversed in `sed` is two invocations of `sed`: `sed '1,/#GENE_ANNOTATIONS/d' file.txt | sed '1d'`.

Comment: @A.Danischewski: Yes, both are possible. Thank you for your hints.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ni '/^#GENE_ANNOTATIONS/,$!b;n;n;:a;p;n;ba' mydirectory/*
```

Only print the lines you want by enabling the `-n` switch.

Another alternative:

```
sed  '/^#GENE_ANNOTATIONS/,$!d;x;/./{g;b};x;h;N;d' mydirectory/*
```